# How to get multiple event_params as column in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

**What I need**: total occurrences of event and the data associated to this event.

**What I tried:** in the devices I sent some events to Firebase Analytics. Events look like:

```
event_name = "business_global_view_profile"
```

with params:

```
business_global_name :String
business_global_city:String
business_global_ID:String
```

So in BigQuery I got something like (between a lot more of values and events that are not need for this):

[image]

I need to obtain ONLY the params I sent, so I need to discard all the stuff like `ga_session_id`, `firebase_event_origin`, etc...

So first I tried to "filter" the event I need from all the other events :

```
SELECT params.key AS ParamKey, params.value.string_value as Value
FROM `xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx`,
UNNEST(event_params) as params
WHERE event_name = "business_global_view_profile"
```

After that I get a table like:

[image]

At this moment I achieved get the count of the occurrences by ID

```
SELECT Value AS BusinessID, COUNT(Value) Occurrences
  FROM(SELECT params.key AS ParamKey, params.value.string_value as Value
  FROM `xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx`,
  UNNEST(event_params) as params
  WHERE event_name = "business_global_view_profile"
  AND event_date = "20190409")
WHERE ParamKey = "business_global_ID"
Group by Value
```

[image]

But here is where I'm lost, because What I need is something like:

```
|BusinessID | Occurrences | BusinessName | BusinessCity |
```

Where

- `BusinessName = business_global_name`
- `BusinessCity = business_global_city`

How can I get all this info together? For sure there is a shorter way to do it, but I'm haven't worked to much with SQL

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I caught your requirement correctly, but here is a possible solution. I used the following schema for simplicity:

[image]

And came up with the following query:

```
SELECT occ_count.BusinessID, occ_count.Occurrences, flat_data.BusinessName, flat_data.BusinessCity
FROM
(
SELECT params.value AS BusinessID, count(params.value) AS Occurrences
FROM `XXXX.XXXX.XXXX`, UNNEST(event_params) as params
WHERE event_name = 'business_global_view_profile'
AND event_date = "20190409"
AND params.key = 'business_global_id'
GROUP BY params.value
) AS occ_count
JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT arr1.value AS BusinessID, arr2.value AS BusinessName, arr3.value as BusinessCity
FROM `XXXX.XXXX.XXXX`, UNNEST(event_params) as arr1, UNNEST(event_params) arr2, UNNEST(event_params) arr3
WHERE arr2.key = 'business_global_name'
AND arr3.key = 'business_global_city'
) AS flat_data
ON occ_count.BusinessID = flat_data.BusinessID
```

Please note that I'm assuming that for any `business_global_id` there is a single combination of `business_global_name` and `business_global_city`. I'm also taking the values from `event_params.value` instead of `event_params.value.string_value`, as mentioned before, for simplicty.

Comment: Could you explain your query? For example, it looks like you're doing a join between a query that calculates the number of occurrences and a query that unnests as many event_param as necessary?